# Saving iPhone Data Persistently

Tags: iphone

I am making a fitness app that will save your weight, reps, and sets performed for each exercise you perform. I will also use this to track the progress made using this data. Does anyone have any clue how to do so? I've made apps before, but never required the saving of persistent data. Any info would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should investigate [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/_index.html) and [User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
In your case it sounds like you will need a database so Core Data is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect job for **Core Data**

> The Core Data framework provides generalized and automated solutions to common tasks associated with object life-cycle and object graph management, including persistence.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data you're considering generating and how complex the data itself is, if the amount of data is "small", a simple dictionary might work. They can be saved and read pretty easily. However, there are limitations on what data types you can have in a dictionary (or an array) that you then write out. And, from a performance perspective, if you get too much data, writing and reading it can be slow...

I'll re-iterate the recommendation for Core Data, but wanted to mention the other options for completeness. :-)